# Copying Cyrillic URLs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, url, cyrillic

Has anyone solved the problem with copying and pasting links from Cyrillic?

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

In chromium bug copying and pasting links from Cyrillic :-(

**What is the expected result?**

expect a normal copy and paste links from the Cyrillic alphabet

```
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аррасская_уния
```

**What happens instead?**

paste URL

```
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F
```

[Issue 68718](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=68718)

Comment: I copy-pasted your url examples(both) and it opened proper page in Firefox, IE9,8,10 and Chrome. So what are you talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is still not resolved! A couple of years ago I developed a Google Chrome extension that might be useful for you!

[COPY URL extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-url/mkhnbhdofgaendegcgbmndipmijhbili)

Advantages:

- supports links copying with Cyrillic
- automatically converts Punycode

When you click "Copy URL” address of open tabs is copied to the clipboard.

I was developing it for myself so the localization is coming soon!

Comment: Now returns 404

Comment: Great extension but it's removed from store(

Answer (score 20):

Just add any character and then erase it. After this operation, the copied cyrillic character will not be converted to punycode.

Example. In the address bar "[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аррасская_уния](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)" -> "[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аррасская_уния1](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F1)" -> "[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аррасская_уния](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)" and then copy it.

Comment: No longer works in Chrome 93, unfortunately: copying the final `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аррасская_уния` results in Punycode.

Comment: now you need to put the symbol at the beginning

Answer (score 2):

As the other answers are currently not working, I use this website as a workaround:
https://www.webatic.com/url-convertor.

The URL is put in the lower box (Encoded) and Decode button is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

Recipe:

- Press Ctrl-L for the whole URL to be selected.
- Press Shift-Right to deselect `h` (or Shift-Ctrl-Right-Right-Left to deselect `http://` or `https://`).
- Copy the selected text.
- Go to the place where you want the text to be pasted.
- Re-typе the omitted part manually if needed.
- Paste the text.

(This works at least in Chrome 93.)

Answer (score 0):

Since 'COPY URL extension' from drserge's answer is no longer available, you can use this one:
[Copy Unicode URLs](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/copy-unicode-urls/fnbbfiapefhkicjhecnoepbijhanpkjp)